# ERROR ITMS-90075: The application-identifier entitlement is missing

Tags: plist, app-store-connect, testflight, entitlements

When attempting to submit an app to Apple iTunes Connect TestFlight, I get the following error:

> **ERROR ITMS-90075**: "This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is missing; it should contain your 10-character Apple Developer ID, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier."

How should this be fixed in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Entitlements.plist` file should contain the `application-identifier` key.

The value `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)` should resolve the error and give you the correct `application-identifier`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    // ...

    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>

    // ...

</dict>
</plist>
```